# Express Concurrent Http Request

Tags: node.js, express, concurrency, blocking

A user can fire multiple concurrent HTTP requests to express server. In the server-side I want to block all concurrent requests except first request (for that particular user) then perform some action and unblock other requests one by one.

Users' requests should not be blocked by other user's requests.

How to achieve this in nodejs? User's request can be identified (unique) by Authorization header.

Thanks

Comment: This can definitely be done, but my initial thought is that this smells of bad design and you should try a different approach. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by having the user's requests be handled synchronously?

Comment: 'some action' is actually calling API with limits (hits per day). Blocking other than first because first will cache and other request will utilize that data.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to achieve that but simplest i can think of is:

```
var blocked = {};
app.get('/bla', function(req, res){

    var id = getIdFromRequest(req);

    if (blocked[id]) // if true then another request is being served
        return res.send('Concurrent requests not allowed');

    blocked[id] = true;

    // do your thing here

    // and respond
    res.send('some data');

    // unlock the user
    delete blocked[id];
});
```

Comment: This will reject any concurrent requests entirely. I think what they want is to queue those requests and handle them one by one after each preceding one is dealt with.

Comment: It will only reject requests from the same user until the first one is responded to. Then the user can make another request. This code does exactly what is specified in question *I want to block all concurrent requests except first...*

Comment: The second half of that sentence is _then perform some action and unblock other requests one by one_. Asking the requester to resend requests just because you didn't finish processing the first one is ridiculous.